# Angular 6, HttpClient, Detect Data change on backend

Tags: angular, real-time, real-time-updates

I have a `MessageService` like so:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class MessageService {
    private BASE_URL = "http://10.1.1.190/EDSOData/Messages";

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public update(parameters: Object) {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            })
        };

        return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL, parameters, httpOptions);
    }
}
```

`update` inserts a message.  If the app has multiple simultaneous users, how can I detect a change for all of them?

Comment: You should look at websockets

Comment: either all the clients need to be polling for changes or you need to have a websocket implementation so that the server can push changes to the client. This question is too broad for SO. The proper set up depends on your needs and your tech stack / options.

Comment: I think websockets is the answer.  Thank you gentlemen.